# Looking for two specific Lego pieces

Tags: part-identification

[image]

I've been browsing through Bricklink for most of my morning trying to find these two specific LEGO pieces. If someone could help me find the number ID for these, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Sorry for the image quality, it's the best I can do.

Edit: Here's another pic of the first piece: [image]

Edit Edit: Okay so I did find the first piece on Bricklink. It's categorized as a minifig weapon and its' ID is 15071.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cannot recognize the first one as it might be a clone-brand part, but the other is [Pneumatic Hose Connector with Axle Connector](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99021#T=C)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The first piece is: Minifigure, Weapon Gun, Blaster 1 x 2 x 2/3 with Studs on Sides and Handle

[Part # 15071](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15071#T=C)

[image]